# Do I need to write a Route Resolver for every service call that implements a new interface?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, resolver

I have a question about routing in Angular 4, especially dealing with resolving the data.

My app will benefit greatly by implementing a route resolver; however, I am working on a complex web app and In one of my routes (a contact page) there are several components being rendered, each with a different service call to the back end. Each call is implementing a different interface. This is due to database restrictions.

Is their a way I can write 1 resolver for each of my services, or do I need to write a resolver for each service call that implements a new interface?

Comment: I'm not positive I fully understood the question, but if I did, you can write a single resolver for the whole route for the page component that hosts all the sub components that you mentioned. In this resolver you would use `Observable.forkJoin` to wait for all of your api calls to finish. Then in your main page component you can just pass the individual pieces of data down into the sub components that need them.

Comment: So I can combine different API calls, each returning different data with an Observable.ForJoin? If so, that should answer my question.

Comment: I did some research on ForkJoin, and I think that is exactly what I need. If you change your comment to a answer, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do everything in a single resolver, like so:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {

     return Observable.forkJoin(
         this.someService.apiCallA(),
         this.someService.apiCallB(),
         this.someService.apiCallC(),
      )
      .map(([resA, resB, resC]: [ResponseAType, ResponseBType, ResponseCType]) => {
            return {
               aData: resA,
               bData: resB,
               cData: resC
            };

      });

}
```

Then in your main page component:

```
constructor(private aRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

      aRoute.data.subscribe((data: any) => {
         // You can find aData, bData, and cData here inside of data
         // Pass them down into the components that need them
      });

   }
```